# Typeclass and type signature

Tags: haskell

I'm experimenting around with type signatures. This one here works:

```
nonz :: (Eq s, Num s, Show s) => ((->) a) s -> a -> Maybe s
nonz f v = let w = f v in if w == 0 then Nothing else Just w
main = do
    print $ nonz (+3) 7
    print $ nonz (+4) (-4)
```

But when I make it a typeclass I get an error:

```
class Nonz z where
    nonz :: (Eq s, Num s, Show s) => z s -> a -> Maybe s
instance Nonz ((->) r) where
    nonz f v = let w = f v in if w == 0 then Nothing else Just w

main = do
    print $ nonz (+3) 7
    print $ nonz (+4) (-4)
```

Types `r` and `a` don't match. How could I tie them together?

Comment: As a side note, `nonz` doesn't actually seem to use the `Show s` constraint at all. Are you sure you need that constraint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you intend that `Nonz` be applied to type constructors which take two arguments, then you should write your class accordingly. Right now, your class argument has kind `* -> *`. It's likely you meant for it to have kind `* -> * -> *`.

Your class

```
class Nonz z where
    nonz :: (Eq s, Num s, Show s) => z s -> a -> Maybe s
```

Suggested alternative

```
class Nonz z where
    nonz :: (Eq s, Num s, Show s) => z a s -> a -> Maybe s
```

Then your instance can be written

```
instance Nonz (->) where
    nonz f v = let w = f v in if w == 0 then Nothing else Just w
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is almost correct. You can remove the `a` parameter from the signature in the `class` and instead just make `nonz` return `z (Maybe s)`. The internals of `z` can hide `a` as part of its implementation details. Also, the `Show s` is not necessary.

Here is how it should look to compile:

```
class Nonz z where
    nonz :: (Eq s, Num s) => z s -> z (Maybe s)

instance Nonz ((->) a) where
    nonz f v = let w = f v in if w == 0 then Nothing else Just w

main = do
    print $ nonz (+3) 7
    print $ nonz (+4) (-4)
```

This works because the `a` variable is irrelevant to the `Nonz` class, and so it can be hidden inside the implementation. When the implementation is `((->) a)`, then the instance function's signature would become:

```
nonz :: (Eq s, Num s) => ((->) a) s -> ((->) a) (Maybe s)
```

which, by using infix notation and removing parentheses, is the same as:

```
nonz :: (Eq s, Num s) => (a -> s) -> a -> Maybe s
```

---

You might further notice that now the signature of `nonz` looks a lot like an operation on a functor. You would be correct. You could actually implement `Nonz` for any type that implements `Functor` by using this implementation:

```
nonz' :: (Eq s, Num s) => s -> Maybe s
nonz' w = if w == 0 then Nothing else Just w

instance Nonz ((->) a) where
    nonz = fmap nonz'
```

And now you might decide to remove the `Nonz` class and just use `fmap nonz'` directly.

Comment: or `[w | w /= 0]`, with MonadComprehensions.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I wanted to understand how a function can be a Functor instance. So your answer helps me perfectly. Here's the full working example:

```
nonz' :: (Eq s, Num s) => (a -> s)   -> a -> Maybe s
{-
nonz' :: (Eq s, Num s) => ((->) a s) -> a -> Maybe s
nonz' :: (Eq s, Num s) => ((->) a) s -> a -> Maybe s
-}
nonz' f v = let w = f v in if w == 0 then Nothing else Just w

class Nonz z where
    nonz :: (Eq s, Num s) => z a s -> a -> Maybe s
instance Nonz (->) where
    nonz f v = let w = f v in if w == 0 then Nothing else Just w

main = do
    print $ nonz' (+3) 7
    print $ nonz' (+4) (-4)
    print $ nonz' length "foo"
    print $ nonz' length ""
    print $ nonz (+3) 7
    print $ nonz (+4) (-4)
    print $ nonz length "foo"
    print $ nonz length ""
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm glad you mentioned `Functor`. I used that idea to write another version of your class. Please see my answer.